# Sysadmin can't see tables from .net application

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a login that has been granted sysadmin and can select/insert/update/delete in a query within sql management studio.

I have a third party .net application that is using the same login and get the following error:

> Invalid object name 'tablename'.

I am able alter the query to `select 'blah'` and it will return the results successfully.

Does anyone have an idea why I can't run queries from my third party application?

Comment: I have tried giving permissions at the database level and the table level as well.

Comment: Try providing schema name along with the table name.

Comment: Please show us your connection string. If you are using things like `User Instance` and `AttachDbFileName`, I bet I know the problem! Also, does your reference to tablename include the schema? Is it possible you created yourschema.tablename and they're trying to see dbo.tablename?

Comment: <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=WS-RH; Initial Catalog=db; User ID=user; Password=pw; Connection Timeout=0;" />

Comment: I tried using dbo.table in the query and recieved the same error

Comment: the user has the default schema of dbo.

Comment: is the application connected to the correct instance and using the correct database?

Comment: yes, i can run queries fine in management studio using the same credentials on the same server/db

Comment: i can also run queries on that server/db through the .net application but i cant cant see the tables... for example i can execute the same query:  select 'hi' which doesnt need to use tables

Answer (score 0):

After spending several hours on this, I found out it was due to nested transactions.  I had a transaction started in the .net app and in the sql file.